# Capturing the 'when' value

Tags: kotlin

Is there a way to capture the value that controls the flow in a `when` statement?

```
when(some expression) {
    "one" -> println("two")
    "two" -> println("three")
    else -> println("Error: ${???} is not a recognised option.")
}
```

How should we get the value represented above by `{???}`?

Comment: store some expression in a variable and use that variable in when ..

Comment: You want to print the result of "some expression" in place of "${???}"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can assign the result of the evaluated expression to a constant and use it as argument to the *when* clause:

```
when(val result = ...your expression here...) {
  "one" -> println("two")
  "two" -> println("three")
  else -> println("Error: $result is not a recognised option.")
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for! I was trying to avoid assigning a variable just before the `when` statement, but didn't realise you could assign it _inside_ the statement! Looking at the Kotlin documentation, this is a small paragraph at the very end of the section, that's why I had missed it.